Duplicate class org.hamcrest on android studio
I have the following error and I don't know how to solve this problem, please help
Duplicate class org.hamcrest.BaseDescription found in modules hamcrest-core-1.1.jar -> hamcrest-core-1.1 (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1) and junit-4.10.jar -> junit-4.10 (junit:junit:4.10)
Duplicate class org.hamcrest.BaseMatcher found in modules hamcrest-core-1.1.jar -> hamcrest-core-1.1 (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1) and junit-4.10.jar -> junit-4.10 (junit:junit:4.10)
Duplicate class org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers found in modules hamcrest-core-1.1.jar -> hamcrest-core-1.1 (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1) and junit-4.10.jar -> junit-4.10 (junit:junit:4.10)
Duplicate class org.hamcrest.Description found in modules hamcrest-core-1.1.jar -> hamcrest-core-1.1 (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1) and junit-4.10.jar -> junit-4.10 (junit:junit:4.10)
Duplicate class org.hamcrest.Factory found in modules hamcrest-core-1.1.jar -> hamcrest-core-1.1 (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1) and junit-4.10.jar -> junit-4.10 (junit:junit:4.10)
Duplicate class org.hamcrest.Matcher found in modules hamcrest-core-1.1.jar -> hamcrest-core-1.1 (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1) and junit-4.10.jar -> junit-4.10 (junit:junit:4.10)
Duplicate class org.hamcrest.SelfDescribing found in modules hamcrest-core-1.1.jar -> hamcrest-core-1.1 (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1) and junit-4.10.jar -> junit-4.10 (junit:junit:4.10)
Duplicate class org.hamcrest.StringDescription found in modules hamcrest-core-1.1.jar -> hamcrest-core-1.1 (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1) and junit-4.10.jar -> junit-4.10 (junit:junit:4.10)
Duplicate class org.hamcrest.core.AllOf found in modules hamcrest-core-1.1.jar -> hamcrest-core-1.1 (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1) and junit-4.10.jar -> junit-4.10 (junit:junit:4.10)
Duplicate class org.hamcrest.core.AnyOf found in modules hamcrest-core-1.1.jar -> hamcrest-core-1.1 (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1) and junit-4.10.jar -> junit-4.10 (junit:junit:4.10)
Duplicate class org.hamcrest.core.DescribedAs found in modules hamcrest-core-1.1.jar -> hamcrest-core-1.1 (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1) and junit-4.10.jar -> junit-4.10 (junit:junit:4.10)
Duplicate class org.hamcrest.core.Is found in modules hamcrest-core-1.1.jar -> hamcrest-core-1.1 (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1) and junit-4.10.jar -> junit-4.10 (junit:junit:4.10)
Duplicate class org.hamcrest.core.IsAnything found in modules hamcrest-core-1.1.jar -> hamcrest-core-1.1 (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1) and junit-4.10.jar -> junit-4.10 (junit:junit:4.10)
Duplicate class org.hamcrest.core.IsEqual found in modules hamcrest-core-1.1.jar -> hamcrest-core-1.1 (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1) and junit-4.10.jar -> junit-4.10 (junit:junit:4.10)
Duplicate class org.hamcrest.core.IsInstanceOf found in modules hamcrest-core-1.1.jar -> hamcrest-core-1.1 (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1) and junit-4.10.jar -> junit-4.10 (junit:junit:4.10)
Duplicate class org.hamcrest.core.IsNot found in modules hamcrest-core-1.1.jar -> hamcrest-core-1.1 (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1) and junit-4.10.jar -> junit-4.10 (junit:junit:4.10)
Duplicate class org.hamcrest.core.IsNull found in modules hamcrest-core-1.1.jar -> hamcrest-core-1.1 (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1) and junit-4.10.jar -> junit-4.10 (junit:junit:4.10)
Duplicate class org.hamcrest.core.IsSame found in modules hamcrest-core-1.1.jar -> hamcrest-core-1.1 (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1) and junit-4.10.jar -> junit-4.10 (junit:junit:4.10)
Duplicate class org.hamcrest.internal.ArrayIterator found in modules hamcrest-core-1.1.jar -> hamcrest-core-1.1 (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1) and junit-4.10.jar -> junit-4.10 (junit:junit:4.10)
Duplicate class org.hamcrest.internal.SelfDescribingValue found in modules hamcrest-core-1.1.jar -> hamcrest-core-1.1 (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1) and junit-4.10.jar -> junit-4.10 (junit:junit:4.10)
Duplicate class org.hamcrest.internal.SelfDescribingValueIterator found in modules hamcrest-core-1.1.jar -> hamcrest-core-1.1 (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1) and junit-4.10.jar -> junit-4.10 (junit:junit:4.10)

My Android source is as follows
package com.packge.webview;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView mWebView;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout mySwipeRefreshLayout;
    private ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener mOnScrollChangedListener;

    @SuppressLint({"SetJavaScriptEnabled", "MissingInflatedId"})
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {



        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mWebView = findViewById(R.id.web_view);
        mySwipeRefreshLayout = this.findViewById(R.id.swipeContainer);

        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
        mWebView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        String siteUrl = "https://website.com";
        mWebView.loadUrl(siteUrl);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);


                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "درحال بارگذاری...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                mySwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "بارگذاری به اتمام رسید", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "خطایی رخ داد! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //Clear WebView
                try {
                    view.stopLoading();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    view.clearView();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (view.canGoBack()) {
                    view.goBack();
                }
                String ErrorPagePath = "file:///assets/index.html";
                view.loadUrl(ErrorPagePath);

                super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
            }


        });
        mWebView.loadUrl(siteUrl);

        mySwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(
                new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onRefresh() {
                        mWebView.reload();
                    }
                });



    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        mySwipeRefreshLayout.getViewTreeObserver()
                .addOnScrollChangedListener(mOnScrollChangedListener =
                        new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onScrollChanged() {
                                mySwipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(mWebView.getScrollY() == 0);

                            }
                        });
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mySwipeRefreshLayout.getViewTreeObserver()
                .removeOnScrollChangedListener(mOnScrollChangedListener);
    }



}

activity_main is
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipeContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/web_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
</androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
    

</RelativeLayout>

and gradle is
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application)
}

android {
    namespace 'com.packge.webview'
    compileSdkVersion 34
    buildToolsVersion '35.0.0 rc3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.packge.webview"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 34
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    buildToolsVersion '35.0.0 rc3'
}

dependencies {

    implementation libs.appcompat
    implementation libs.material
    testImplementation libs.junit
    androidTestImplementation libs.ext.junit
    androidTestImplementation libs.espresso.core

        implementation libs.guava
        implementation libs.swiperefreshlayout
        implementation libs.testng
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
        androidTestImplementation libs.espresso.core
        constraints {
            implementation ("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.8.0") {
                because("kotlin-stdlib-jdk7 is now a part of kotlin-stdlib")
            }
            implementation ("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.8.0") {
                because("kotlin-stdlib-jdk8 is now a part of kotlin-stdlib")
            }
        }
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation libs.appcompat.v170beta01



}

please help
I tested the config solution but it didn't work and I faced another error and even after add this:
testImplementation 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1'

not solved
Building a webview software that showed such an error when outputting. Unfortunately, I do not know the solution and I need help. I did not find a solution on the Internet, or the solutions provided did not solve the problem
